# indexPathsForVisibleRows with cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

How can I remove from array [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]  cell? I want to have only headers and footers

Comment: Headers and footers are not cells in your tableview. What exactly do you want to achieve? Get only the visible headers and footers or also the visible cells?

Comment: @chrisblomm, I want Get only the visible headers and footers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this (according to Apple's delegate/dataSource paradigm) is to call `[self.tableview reloadData]`. Then in your data source methods, return 0 for the number of rows.